# How to send data to server in Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

In my application i have 3 text fields. I need to send those values to server. Already my server is hosted somewhere. If the values are matched i need to get the SUCCESS response message. 
Can we use the JSON Objects to communicate between client and server in C++.

Comment: Are you trying to implement an HTTP interface that your application should call, or are you making a socket connection to a server? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I don't know in depth. I have 3 values. That 3 values is already stored in server. If the 3 values match then the response from server is SUCCESS otherwise FAIL. Already back end server side programming is done from someone. Now i just want to send the 3 values to that server.

Comment: I don't know in depth. I have 3 values. That 3 values is already stored in server. If the 3 values match then the response from server is SUCCESS otherwise FAIL. Already back end server side programming is done from someone. Now i just want to send the 3 values to that server. ( I am trying to implement in HTTP interface). dirk

Comment: Just to be clear, Qt Creator is an IDE for Qt programming.

Comment: I gave a +1 because someone gave a -1. This is a very legitimate question. This person has no idea what http is. Let's be kind and positive and educate him/her.

Comment: since he wants to work with JSON probably he wants to be able to simply make http `GET` and `POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably QNetworkAccessManager is what you're looking for. I gues that you want to make some http requests to this "server". In case it is not what you're looking for, then you should specify what kind of protocol uses your server.